# Create a JQM Custom Loading Message

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a working Jquery Mobile loading message below:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Fetching Operators");
```

however I wish to do this,

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "<div class='clearfix'>Fetching Operators</div><a href='default.aspx'>Use Simple Site</a>");
```

so that if the user has a slow conn they can opt to click the link to the simply site.

The HTML however does not render, but rather all just shows as text. Can anyone tell me how to achieve the above?

Thanks very much for the assistance.

Regards Devin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery Mobile does not allow HTML to be used by default (the `.text()` method is most likely used internally rather than the `.html()` method), and it also looks like each time you call the `$.mobile.loading()` method (the new version of the method you're running) that the text for the loader gets reset.

Here's a quick (dirty) solution for jQuery Mobile 1.2:

```
//show the loader, specifying to show the text message
$.mobile.loading( 'show', { textVisible : true } );

//now find the loader widget, find the text within it, and then set it's HTML
$("body").find(".ui-loader").find("h1").html("<div class='clearfix'>Fetching Operators</div><a href='default.aspx'>Use Simple Site</a>");
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nABCq/

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I have been trying to replicate your solution but for what ever reason my site which is running JQM 1.2.0 will not display your solution. It only shows the loader wheel with the word loading. As if it is ignoring your second line. Do you know why?

Comment: Here on inspection I can see that your second line has not been applied: <div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-verbose"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div>

Comment: Found the problem. Within an ASPX is a form element which was the immediate child. Therefore to make this work for my aspx page I merely needed to change 'body' to 'form'... Perfect and thank you!

Comment: @user1434739 Thanks for updating on your progress. I didn't think about how ASPX would add the `form` element, I'm sure other frameworks add HTML structure like that as well. I updated my code to use `.find()` rather than `.children()`.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a potential performance cost to this change?

Comment: @user1434739 Sure, but not a big cost. You're making a relatively small change to the DOM which will cause the browser to re-draw the region of the loading spinner/message. Since the loader widget is placed absolutely it's not part of the regular flow of the document layout, meaning it's impact on performance will be minimal (Hint: if you want to animate something, position it absolutely, your users will thank you).